# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una suma dentro de un count distinc con un sub select?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Trato de realizar una consulta que me permita obtener una tabla con los resultados de ID, cantidad_bancos, cantidad transacciones y Monto_total. Lo que pasa es que los bancos, tienen un nombre que se puede repetir 'n' cantidad de veces (Por ejemplo: Banco Valencia, Banco Internacional, etc.), entonces estoy interesada en saber para cada usuario cuántos bancos tiene (2, 5, 6, sumando solamente los únicos), así como su las transacciones totales por todos los bancos y el monto total por todos los bancos. Hice esto, pero me da un error, llevo rato dándole cabeza pero no sé cómo puedo solucionarlo:

```
SELECT 
B.ID
,SUM(B.NombreBanco)
,COUNT(B.Monto) as Cantidad_transacciones
,SUM(B.Monto) as Monto_total 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.NombreBanco) FROM Bancos AS A
WHERE A.ID = B.ID AS CANTIDAD_BANCOS)
FROM Bancos as B
WHERE B.FechaID between '20200101' and '20200731'
and B.Servicio !='AWS' 
and B.Flujo = 'A'
and B.Traspaso = '1'
group by B.ID
order by B.ID
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Saludos, por favor indica el error que te da ese código. Ya que los demás no tenemos tu base de datos para comprobarlo

Answer (score 0):

Intenta algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE Bancos (
ID NVARCHAR(8),
NombreBanco NVARCHAR(8),
Monto INT );

INSERT INTO Bancos  
VALUES ('111', 'BCO_A', 101),  
       ('111', 'BCO_B', 102),  
       ('111', 'BCO_B', 103),  
       ('222', 'BCO_A', 104),  
       ('222', 'BCO_A', 105),  
       ('222', 'BCO_B', 106),  
       ('222', 'BCO_C', 107),  
       ('333', 'BCO_A', 108),  
       ('333', 'BCO_B', 109),  
       ('333', 'BCO_B', 110),  
       ('333', 'BCO_A', 111),  
       ('333', 'BCO_C', 112);
       
SELECT ID, 
       COUNT(ID) Cantidad_transacciones, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT NombreBanco) Cantidad_bancos, 
       SUM(Monto) Monto_total
  FROM Bancos
 GROUP BY ID
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para este caso, serviría si tengo pocos registros. Mi tabla tiene más de 2 millones de registros.

Comment: ¿Pero te refieres a que se demora mucho?, al menos en el resultado, esta query entrega la cantidad total de transacciones, cantidad de bancos distintos, y el monto total por ID, independiente del tamaño de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

si NombreBanco es un varchar, entonces esa es una fuente de error ya que no se puede sumar un varchar, prueba con esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
B.ID
,COUNT(B.NombreBanco)
,COUNT(B.Monto) as Cantidad_transacciones
,SUM(B.Monto) as Monto_total 
,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.NombreBanco) FROM Bancos AS A WHERE A.ID = B.ID) CANTIDAD_BANCOS
FROM Bancos as B
WHERE B.FechaID between '20200101' and '20200731'
and B.Servicio !='AWS' 
and B.Flujo = 'A'
and B.Traspaso = '1'
group by B.ID
order by B.ID
```

Comment: Hola! No funciona, me da este mismo error que me ha estado dando Incorrect syntax near 'CANTIDAD_BANCOS'.

Comment: @Sharon, tal vez sea debido a que falta una coma, checa la consulta editada, le agregue la coma faltante